# QtCreator cannot find cmake

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, qt-creator

My QtCreator cannot find the new version of cmake I installed (I removed the old one).
All I could do was to set the path of cmake to `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/MacOS/CMake` in Preferences|Build&Run|CMake. I found no other settings to specify details of the new cmake executable.

How can I make it work?

I successfully tested cmake from the command line.

Tools: QtCreator 3.1.0, cmake 3.0.1, OSX Mavericks 10.9.4

Comment: Maybe that's a wrong path ? try `whereis cmake` in console

Comment: From `whereis cmake` I get nothing. Does it mean it is not in the paths searched by default? Shouldn't they usually be updated by the program being installed?

Comment: Ohh, I think I made a mistake, probably `which cmake` is a command to go, it widens the search, maybe it will return something.

Comment: Get cmake location and check your paths. If cmake is somewhere in /opt/bin/cmake and you don't have it in your PATH variable - update your shell profile and that's it. Another way is to specify full path to cmake in QtCreator

Comment: @prajmus: I get nothing from 'which cmake', either.

Comment: @Tanuki: I specified the full path in QtCreator, with no success.

Comment: Did you check the path to compiler? Do you have the compiler installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the wrong path for cmake, which pointed to the GUI cmake utility. The correct one is:

> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake

Answer (score 1):

From within QtCreator:

- First define a default **CMAKE tool** in :
  **Tools > Options > CMake Tab**
  Enter the path to your CMAKE executable.
- Then in **Tools > Options > Kits** this is necessary to specify the CMake Tool specified earlier.
- Optional but recommended:
  Check that the **CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM** variable is set to the desired value once you have created your project and then **Build > Run CMake**.
  To check this go into The **Project Tab** then **Build & Run > Build Settings**.
  In this panel the **CMAKE Build** configuration will appear with all the CMAKE variables current value, which in case can be overridden.